# extract dict from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
'''[ERROR] 2020-10-01T04:46:37.sdfsdqs889dgsdg9dgdf {
"correlation_id": "asdfsdf-dsfasdfa-adfadsf-asdf",
"invocation_timestamp": null,
"invoked_component": "lambda",
"invoker_agent": null,
"message": {
"errorMessage": "Unauthorized",
"statusCode": 401
},
"message_type": "ERROR",
"original_source_app": "",
"response_timestamp": "2020-10-01 04:46:37.121436",
"status": 401,
"target_idp_application": "",
"timezone": "UTC"
}'''
```

How would I convert this string to only contain the dict object inside of it?

such as:

```
{
"correlation_id": "asdfsdf-dsfasdfa-adfadsf-asdf",
"invocation_timestamp": null,
"invoked_component": "lambda",
"invoker_agent": null,
"message": {
"errorMessage": "Unauthorized",
"statusCode": 401
},
"message_type": "ERROR",
"original_source_app": "",
"response_timestamp": "2020-10-01 04:46:37.121436",
"status": 401,
"target_idp_application": "",
"timezone": "UTC"
}
```

Comment: You will have to deserialize it. How did you get that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this to get the string form

```
test = '''[ERROR] 2020-10-01T04:46:37.sdfsdqs889dgsdg9dgdf {
"correlation_id": "asdfsdf-dsfasdfa-adfadsf-asdf",
"invocation_timestamp": null,
"invoked_component": "lambda",
"invoker_agent": null,
"message": {
"errorMessage": "Unauthorized",
"statusCode": 401
},
"message_type": "ERROR",
"original_source_app": "",
"response_timestamp": "2020-10-01 04:46:37.121436",
"status": 401,
"target_idp_application": "",
"timezone": "UTC"
}'''

print(test[test.find('{'):]) # find the first '{' and discard all characters before that index in the string
```

and you could do this if you want it as a dict object

```
import json
dict_form = json.loads(test[test.find('{'):]) # same as before now sending it to json.loads which converts a string to a dict object (as most requests are sent as a string)
print(dict_form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

res = json.loads(string_var)
print(res)

Now you can use res dict to access it.

Comment: that will not work on the given string as there will be a JSONDecodeError without indexing to only include the dict object.